# Are lenses like this actually available?

Tags: lens

Is a lens like the one below actually available?
[image]

This is a screenshot from a [movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1851988/). The photographer in the movie uses this lens to covertly photograph the scene happening to his right using this lens.

So I was curious to know whether this type of lens is actually available? If available what is the **name for these kind of lens and their features**?

Comment: The lens is a 50mm f/1.8(widely available). The tube on the end is another contraption, but not a lens :)

Comment: @dpollitt +1 for the detail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure, they are called Angle Mirror Lenses

You can buy one here: [http://www.amazon.com/Opteka-Voyeur-Right-Digital-Cameras/dp/B000F49052](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000F49052)

Although I must say they are a bit creepy, even the product name is creepy... You'd do better to learn to interact with the people you want to photograph.

Comment: So it's not a lens as-such but an attachment that goes on the front of another lens? I also figure any photo taken with this will be flipped horizontally.  If it's important (if there's any writing in the image such as a sign), it'll need flipping back in PP.

Comment: Product description is very creepy: `This lens can be a valuable asset when shooting still pictures at the beach, pool, and other public places.`

Comment: If you have a front-rotating lens, this can be a joy to use...

Answer (score 4):

It's not a lens as such, it's just a right-angle mirror in an adapter that fits onto the filter ring of a lens. It's just a mirror in a tube, really. There's usually a plain piece of glass or a really cheap plastic lens element in the front of the tube to make it look more like a lens front the front.

It may be called a "right-angle mirror lens hood" or a "super spy lens"; it's very widely available and made by a number of manufacturers in a number of sizes to fit different lenses. They range in price from about $US 25 to $US 100, depending on the maker and the size. The Photodiox brand is available through Amazon. It's also available from a number of makers on eBay and from specialty online retailers like photojojo.com.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this looks like "[The Super-Secret Spy Lens](http://photojojo.com/store/awesomeness/candid-photography-spy-lens/)" which you can attach to your existing lens and shoot on a 90° angle.